# ASP.NET CORE Page Flicker

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I recently started developing an ASP.NET Core SPA application that uses Angular 2. I am using a third party css library, along side bootstrap to determine a lot of the page styles. For some reason, I see a page flicker, sometimes with unstyled html and other pages with styled html just reloaded again. I've included the style sheet and other assets in the wwwroot/dist folder and link tags in the _Layout.cshtml page of the application. I've used chrome developer tools to try and debug the application and learned that the html is loaded once and the majority of the time spent loading the page is used on javascript.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want us to do just guess? how about including some code

Comment: There isn't really any code to post, nothing has error-ed out. I believe it's more of a problem regarding structure or the method in which I'm executing the code. I was wondering if anyone has encountered the same or similar problem before.

Comment: This is code related issue there is code to post, but chances there is a simple solution like just having to move you're css scripts into the header.  but I no one will know with out you posting your layout.cshml

Comment: You will have to go through your research to eventually get a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using WebPack? This will bundle all your styles into a javascript file, load that file, and then process them. This processing occurs AFTER page load, so there is a period when your page has no style.

Then, once the javascript bundle is processed, style is applied, and all looks normal.

Use the webpack "MiniCssExtractPlugin" to extract your style into a separate CSS file, which you can include in the header of your pages (rather than a javascript version)